# How to normalize deep nested data in the ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux, ngrx, database-normalization

I am using `ngrx/store` and `Angular 6`. I have deep nested structure in the store. But i feel like it is not correct way to keep it like this:

```
const state = [
  {
    aliases: ['alias1', 'alias2'],
    isRequired: false,
    isSensitive: false,
    name: 'Adress',
    timezoneId: 'UTC',
    children: []
  },
  {
    aliases: ['alias3', 'alias4'],
    isRequired: true,
    isSensitive: false,
    name: 'Phone',
    timezoneId: 'UTC-5',
    children: [
      {
        aliases: ['alias1', 'alias2'],
        isRequired: true,
        isSensitive: false,
        name: 'Sub-Phone',
        timezoneId: 'UTC-5',
        children: [
          {
            aliases: ['alias-phone1', 'alias-phone2'],
            isRequired: false,
            isSensitive: true,
            name: 'Sub-Sub-Phone',
            timezoneId: 'UTC',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here property `name` is like `id`, it can't be the same at the same level, but it can in the children. For example `Sub-Phone` and `Sub-Sub-Phone` could be named `Phone`. What is the best way to keep such type of structure in the store that will be easy to change. Because now if want to change `name: 'Phone'` i should return in reducer full this object with all his children.
How i can normalize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern is to follow [this guide](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape), to normalize state shape.
Do not nest. Create an id that stores the entities. And then create an id that stores the relations (the children, in you scenario).
I have built a sample state for you

```
const state = {
  objects: {
    id: ['Address', 'Phone', 'Sub-Phone', 'Sub-Sub-Phone'],
    entities: {
      'Address': {
        isRequired: false,
        isSensitive: false,
        timezoneId: 'UTC'
      },
      'Phone': {
        isRequired: true,
        isSensitive: false,
        timezoneId: 'UTC-5'
      },
      'Sub-Phone': {
        isRequired: true,
        isSensitive: false,
        timezoneId: 'UTC-5',
      },
      'Sub-Sub-Phone': {
        isRequired: false,
        isSensitive: true,
        timezoneId: 'UTC',
      }
    }
  },
  children: {
    'Address': [],
    'Phone': ['Sub-Phone'],
    'Sub-Phone': ['Sub-Sub-Phone']
  }
}
```

Note that the state has 2 levels: one for the objects, one for the children. The `objects` stores the ids and the entities. The children, store one array for each object key with its children. Note that in ny example there is only one children in the arrays, but you can have something like

```
'Phone': '['Sub-Phone', 'Sub-Phone2', 'Sub-Phone3']
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. But as i mention `name` can be the same. This will works only if i will have unique identifier for every object like id. Because this will not work:
`children: {
    'Address': [],
    'Phone': '['Phone'],
    'Phone': ['Phone']
  }`

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the server implementation, normalization could be done there directly. More likely, however, you are going to normalize the state in the client using a third party library, e.g., [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).

There are several articles discussing this topic, for example [this one on Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/what-i-have-learned-using-ngrx-redux-with-angular-2-20a748149661).

Answer (score 1):

@ngrx/entity is very neat way to normalize your store.
look at this [@ngrx/entity ReadMe](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/entity/README.md).

also, it comes with powerful entity adapter and selectors.

Comment: I am already used it in my project. But i find it is not very usefull with deep nested store structure. And as i mention for @Christian Benseler - i don't have ids there and names can be the same

Comment: OK. the choice of using ID is totally up to you, however. I recommend use uuid or other type of ID generator for your state. as your application grow, it will be come handy.